# How do you update a variable in a php file via a form submit? Such as a static password

Tags: php, forms, password-protection, change-password

Being a new to PHP I did a ton of research and could not find the answer to this question. To give some details, I have a small upload web app that uses PHP and Javascript. In what I call the admin section which is username and password protected a user can access the uploaded files.

At this point I am setting a static username and password in php file and storing them as the following variables.

```
$username = "admin";
$password ="admin";
```

The login page then reads the form post to verify if the username and password entered matches what has been set. Once authenticated it sets a session token. This all works great but I would like for people to be able to change the password within the admin.php section.

So I want to have a change password form on the admin.php that when a person submits it then updates the $password variable in the login.php file. How can I write to the existing login.php file and update the static variable $password.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATED: My current login.php file

So as you can see the username and password are statically set, once a person enters the login info and it verifies it sets a session variable. I want a way for a person on the admin.php page to be able to submit a form to update the $password var. I am reading over this right now [change admin password (need to make form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742976/change-admin-password-need-to-make-form?rq=1)

```
<?php //Password Protected Area
session_start();
if($_GET['action'] == 'logout'){
   unset($_SESSION['currentUser']); 
}

$requestMethod = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
if($requestMethod == 'post'){
    $username = "admin";
    $password ="admin";
    $postUsername = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $postPassword = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    if(($postUsername == $username) && ($postPassword == $password)){
        $_SESSION['currentUser'] = 'admin';
        header("location: admin.php");
    }else{
        $loginError = true;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Login</title>

    <?php include_once "assets/includes/loader.php" ?>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="upload-text" >
        <h1>Please Login</h1>


         <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" id="loginForm"> 

          <?php if($loginError){?>
            <h2>Login Error:</h2>
            <p>Sorry, your username or password was incorrect.</p>
          <?php } ?>
            <br>
            <label><span>Username:</span> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_POST['username'];?>" /></label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label><span>Password:</span> <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
            <br><br>
            <label><input type="submit" value="Login" /></label>
        </form>     

    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- #upload-wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED:

I worked with provided suggestions and got it working. See updated code below. I created a config.php file and have stored login info there. Using an include to the login.php file I am calling the info. Once authenticated the admin.php file has a form which uses and fwrite to update the conif.php file.

Login.php

```
$requestMethod = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
if($requestMethod == 'post'){
    include "assets/includes/config.php";
    $postUsername = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $postPassword = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    if(($postUsername == $username) && ($postPassword == $password)){
        $_SESSION['currentUser'] = 'admin';
        header("location: admin.php");
    }else{
        $loginError = true;
    }
}
```

admin.php

```
if(isset($_POST['new_pw']) && trim($_POST['new_pw']) != ""){
    $fp = fopen("assets/includes/config.php", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, '<?php');
    fwrite($fp, ' ');
    fwrite($fp, '$username = "admin";');
    fwrite($fp, '$password = "'.trim($_POST['new_pw']).'";');
    fwrite($fp, ' ');
    fwrite($fp, '?>');
    fclose($fp); 
}
?> 

<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="new_pw">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you really want every user to change the password for everybody? What exactly is your goal? Do you want a common user authentication where every user has their own password?

Comment: At some point I am going to distribute this uploads app to clients and or I want to have an option to sell it. I would like a simple way for a NON developer to easily update the password after the app gets distributed with a standard out of the box password. There will only ever be one user account and password so there is no need to add in a DB.

Comment: Take your credentials out of your code into a configuration file of some sort in any case!

Comment: Thats what my plan is but I just need to get this working first. See updated summery.

Comment: Factor it out before you give an option to change it through an GUI. Then use the approach shown below. Furthermore, like this it will be extremely easy to hack, password security applies for this example too!

Comment: ok, I've update my crappy answer with a slightly less horrible one. If it is still not useful, let me know where the confusion is

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER:

create a config file and place it behind the web root. The contents are:

```
<?php
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'admin;
```

Then include the nested config file and remove the `$username` and `$password` declaration from your `$requestMethod` conditional:

```
<?php //Password Protected Area
    session_start();

    if($_GET['action'] == 'logout'){
       unset($_SESSION['currentUser']); 
    }

    $requestMethod = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
    if($requestMethod == 'post'){
        include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path-to-nested-config.php");
        $postUsername = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
        $postPassword = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
        if(($postUsername == $username) && ($postPassword == $password)){
            $_SESSION['currentUser'] = 'admin';
            header("location: admin.php");
        }else{
            $loginError = true;
        }
    }
?>
```

Finally, to update the file you would use [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['new_pw']) && trim($_POST['new_pw']) != "")
{
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path-to-nested-config.php", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, '<?php');
    fwrite($fp, '$username = "admin"');
    fwrite($fp, '$password = "'.trim($_POST['new_pw']).'");
    fclose($fp); 
}
?>
```

This assumes you have a form somewhere that passes "new_pw" to a php script that writes to a config file with proper permissions set to be written by the system.

This is just one way to do it. I chose to do it this way because the config file has 3 lines of code so there's no real need for a fancier system.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's a comment!

Comment: frwite IS his answer. I will gladly update if he explains what he's done or provides SOME code. I don't really feel like writing his whole script for him

Comment: That's what you'd need to do, but if you need this functionality you might want to consider storing it in a database. Also, you should hash your password.

Comment: IMO you should prompt the user via comments first to provide all the information necessary to give a a good answer. Often questions are asked the wrong way, the first answer that springs to your mind may not be what the OP really needs to be told.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am going to give this a try tomorrow. Also I apologize for lack of knowledge. I have mastered Wordpress, HTML, CSS and some javascript over the last year so my next challenge is PHP. Do you have any recommendations on resources for learning PHP. I have just been researching the php.net site and looking at example code on the internet. Thanks again! I will let you know how things go.

Comment: @KaiQing I tried what you said and it worked perfectly with a little re-working. Next task is to do it all in sha1. Also I updated my code above!

Comment: I don't know that I have recommendations for learning PHP except to not be afraid to google search any problems. This site is here for answering what the searches don't. Try this though - you say you're a master of wordpress, which is built in php. Make some plugins. Download some and examine how they work. reverse engineer. You'll learn a lot from that.

Answer (score 0):

As the guys mentioned above this is a very undesired way to do it but if you really have to do it this way then what you should do is 
1- read in the admin file

```
$file = file_get_contents('./admin.php', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

2-replace the current password (which you have it stored in the session with the new password the user gave to you in the form

```
$file=str_replace($oldPass,$newPass,$file);
```

it is also advisable to add the assignment segment to both $oldPass and $newPass to avoid replacing other parts of your code if users entered things that match
3- write the file after replacment

```
$fp=fopen('admin.php','w');
fwrite($fp,$file,strlen($file));
```